# Which browser versions are considered too insecure?

Tags: security

we're trying to analyze some attack vectors on one of our MVC apps and we are considering writing some code to prevent users from accessing our site using a browser[version] that we consider to be too insecure.

For example, anything less than IE 7 is getting banned from our site.

Any browser [+version] that doesn't implement the HttpOnly cookie or has serious known holes/scripting issues would be on our watch list.

Without the obvious sarcastic comments about all versions of IE being totally insecure(!), which browsers and/or versions would you consider to be risky? IE tends to get all the bad press, but what about version 1 of Chrome or version 3 of Safari, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I still think most unsecure browser is IE. There is a lot of crashes and a lot of code execution bugs for IE. In last days of 2012, bluehole 0-day bug discovered being exploited in wild. But I don't remember last bug I've seen which successfully executes shellcode in Windows 7 with DEP and ASLR enabled. Those days almost passed for Firefox and Chrome. Specially chrome sandbox is really secure. I've seen only Vupen found a 0-day vulerability which executed code in Chrome like 1 year ago.

You can see list of vulnerabilities per year, per product and you'll see classification of bugs also.
http://www.cvedetails.com/product/3264/Mozilla-Firefox.html?vendor_id=452

Change product to Chrome, Internet Explorer and Safari.

Also IE is really vulnerable by third-party plugins, you can achieve code-execution easier on IE.

If you have more specific question, please ask.

Comment: thanks for your reply. The link you supplied is really useful and contains lots of excellent information. I appreciate your comment re IE but the fact is we cannot just ban IE outright! We have simply banned IE 7 and back. Other than IE, which VERSIONS of each of the mainstream browsers would you suggest we ban?